Sitecore Same Domain more than 10 Language and diffferent sitecore node
In my Sitecore instance, I have more than 10 languages, all of which belong to the same domain. However, a couple of languages share the same Sitecore node. The solution provided works for defining one language per site.
[https://hishaamn.wordpress.com/2016/12/22/sitecore-multi-sites-with-same-domain-but-different-sitecore-item-node/]
Given that I have more than 10 languages, do I need to define 10 separate site definitions, or is it possible to group the languages under the same site node and define them accordingly?


Hi @Balaji Balasubramanian, Are you trying to load all languages as separate sites like domainname/{langcode}, with a virtual directory?
I hope you are pointing to the same Sitecore node for multiple language code for example like /sitecore/content/SiteA/Home
now you are looking for the site to be loaded like below as it is pointing to same sitecore node
domainname/en-us
domainname/en
domainname/en-CA

OOTB Sitecore, in short to answer your question, you will need to have a site definition for each language. You can have the same domain however, in order for Sitecore to know to which site and which language to target, it will be based on the Site Definition.
Option 1
If you can use Sitecore SXA, this will help you in managing the site definition much easier. With Sitecore SXA, you can also use the master site feature, i.e, a site whose content are shared with other site.
More information at Introducing Sitecore Experience Accelerator
Option 2
Theoretically speaking, You can override the SiteResolver and using the custom attributes languages, you can try to update the virtual path attribute.
